# What does aveRP[0] == 0 and aveRP[0] > 0 in the code means?

Tags: java, cloudsim

```
if(aveRP[0] == 0){}
else if(aveRP[0] > 0){
for(int i = 0 ; i < 100; i++){
double a = r.nextGaussian() * 0.3 + aveRP[0];
if (a < 0 || a > 1){}
else{ relinp.add(a);}
```

where aveRP is an array list of double variable type ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: We assume you know basic Java so it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @JFMeier ,   -difference between using = and == while referencing any element of an array list

Comment: @PeterLawrey i am learning java. This actually is not my code, so trying to understand the code and learning java

Comment: I suggest you read. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ it covers things like the difference between assignment `=` and a check for equality `==`

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks for the suggestion sir, I would go through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aveRP[0] == 0`
This statement is checking whether the first element of array `aveRP` is `0` or not. If it is `0` then no code is executed. The `else` block again checks if it's greater than `0`.

Bottomline, there are many un-necessary validations in your code. The code written in your question is equivalent to :

```
if(aveRP[0] > 0){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 100; i++){
        double a = r.nextGaussian() * 0.3 + aveRP[0];
        if( !(a < 0 || a > 1) ){ relinp.add(a);}
    }
}
```